# calculate $\int \int [x^2+yzf(x^2-y^2)]dydz+[y^2+zxf(x^2-y^2)]dzdx+[z^2+xyf(x^2-y^2)]dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Suppose $\sum$ is the lateral of the space surface $x^2+y^2+z^4=1(z\ge 0)$, $f$ is continuous, calculate the surface integral $$\int \int [x^2+yzf(x^2-y^2)]dydz+[y^2+zxf(x^2-y^2)]dzdx+[z^2+xyf(x^2-y^2)]dxdy$$
>   Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this, can you write down your efforts?

Comment: I think maybe it could be translated into polar coordinates and maybe it can be translated to the easier integration, but I do not know what exactly to do.

Comment: Is f a single variable function?

Comment: Yes.@Divide1918